# Are there any issues when updating from PhpStorm-2016.1.2 to PhpStorm-2017.1?

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, updates, intellij-plugin

I have decided to update my development PC to use PhpStorm-2017.1, but before I update, I do not want to end up wasting 1-2 days re-configuring, if there are any potential issues that can hinder my work.

- Will my current license work on the new version?
- Will my project settings integrate with the update? (Symfony)
- Will my plugins settings be kept? (Symfony)
- Any other thing I need to figure out?

Comment: Any links or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: **1)** install it next to your current version -- IDE settings are stored in separate folders so you can have multiple versions run in parallel (even at the same time) **2)** Backup your project settings (the project that you will be using to check the things) -- `.idea` subfolder. This is if you decide to go back to older version at any time or if you will mess project settings in any way **3)** I had no issues (but I was using every single version); many more people did not had them either. But that does not give 100% guarantee that you will not face any yourself.

Comment: Also: there may be some changes in interface/new functionality/how certain things work/etc that you may not like straight away (well -- it's new .. and first reaction in some people's heads would be like "I do not what that is ... but I want like it was before"). So -- you *may want to check* "What's new" articles for all previous versions first (either on their sit e.. or better their blog/what new videos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [response](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/phpstorm/phpstorm_20171_is_now_released_support_of_codeception_phpunit_6_phpdoc_in_blade_injections_more/#comment-3221028525) form JetBrains:

> It's hard to tell whether your plugins will work with 2017.1 since there are always some changes in API that may affect some of your plugins. So it's easier just to install 2017.1 and see how it goes. Installation won't broke your existing PhpStorm 2016.2 and its settings.
>
> I believe there have been no changes in license server so if you have right on 2017.1 there shouldn't be any problems.

P.s. Thank you every one for your responses. I will be going with the official answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1) Yes, the new installed version will automatically pick up your current license.

2) When you update, only the software is updated. The configuration files are not touched and settings are brought across as they were on the previous version.

3) Same answer as answer # 2

4) Not really. Just download the latest version from their website and install it as you would normally.

Answer (score 2):

upgrading to phpstorm 2017.1 was smooth for me, (once they released some later fixes for things like the REST tool etc)

As for your plugins, it'll depend on what plugins they are, and whether there would be BC breaks.  Look up the plugin documentation and check to see if there's a version for 2017.1.

For what its worth, the symfony plugin works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try official control panel of JetBrains https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/

> Manage product updates with ease
>
> The pace of technologies and software updates is ever-accelerating. Stay up-to-date without compromising your productivity with the Toolbox App: easily maintain several versions of the same tool, install updates, and roll them back instantly if needed.

Could be useful to patch instead of complete update:

> Faster updates
>
> When updating, Toolbox App downloads and applies a patch (or even a set of patches) instead of the full package download, thus saving you time & bandwidth.